# WPF UserControl Dynamic Size / Dock / Anchor & StoryBoard

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

I'm looking for some guidance on creating a WPF UserControl.

My objective is to create an indeterminent progress bar, that slides an image back and forth. I'd like to be able to dock the left and right edges of this user control to the sides of the Window so if the user resizes the window, the width of the progress bar is also increased. I don't care about the height, that can be constant.

Here's what I have, it works great except when I add the control to the form, I cannot set the docking options, and I cannot figure out how to make the storyboard animate to use the full width of the usercontrol.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="WPFStyle.PGBProgress"
    x:Name="MotionProgressBar" Width="550" Margin="5" Height="100" MinWidth="550" MinHeight="100" MaxWidth="550" MaxHeight="100">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Motion" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="127"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="242"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="342"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="433"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:07" Value="433"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="-2"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:07" Value="-2"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="89.705"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="179.29"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="270.032"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="362.902"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:07" Value="717.969"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Motion}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="85.622" Source="image.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your TranslateTransform.X animation with this:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image" 
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                 From="0"
                 To="{Binding ElementName=MotionProgressBar, Path=ActualWidth}"
                 Duration="0:0:7"/>
```

As you can see the real trick is the binding; I bind the `To` property to the UserControl's `ActualWidth`. The same concept can be applied to your other animations, even using KeyFrames (though I find no KeyFrames is a bit easier).

As for the "docking," I think what you are looking for is

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

That will cause your control to fill up all the width it is given.

Comment: This works great; however, I realize now that it animates the image off the right side of the control sicne it moves the X property to the actual width -- is there an easy to bind to (ActualWidth - image.Width)?

Comment: Yes, use a Converter on the binding.

Answer (score 2):

The Docking won't work because you hard-coded the Min/Max size into the control. That doesn't play well with docking. And that is related to the hard-coded animation, see @Charlie's answer.

So, only use size-constraint that are really necessary, like in this case maybe a MinHeight and MinWidth, but leave the rest open.